# How fast can the human hand move?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, estimation, speed, biology

I was playing with my six year old daughter the other day with her toy airplanes (I’m a pilot and she’s very interested in aviation now). I took the little F16 toy and flew it passed her as quickly as I could. It moved fast enough that we couldn’t make it out until my hand was on the other side of my body. She asked, “Daddy, how fast would that be if I was in the cockpit?” That really got me thinking. How fast was I able to move my hand and make the toy jet move, and what would that speed be in a larger scale if it were the real sized thing, scale speed.

Comment: You could try recording yourself spinning and swinging your hand the same way, and count the seconds/milliseconds it takes to perform a whole/half turn of your arm in a circle. After that find out the radius of your arm to your axis of rotation (middle of your body) and you can use some circular motion formulas to get a rough idea of your hands speed.

Comment: I don't think the title and body really match each other, to me they ask different questions. The title seems to be asking what is the max speed a human hand could ever hope to move, while the body seems interested in how fast your specific hand movement was, which as Craig mentioned you can actually calculate with video footage.